# Select players as team and mark in db as selected

Tags: php, sql, multiple-select

i have one table named players with 2 columns: players and status

I need to select unique random teams!
Every team has X players as: Y base and Z pivots
Y and Z its set due input form

If in insert 3 for base and 2 for pivots The result should be like 3 teams or 3 players:

**team 1**
Base 1
Pivot 1
Pivot 2

**team 2**
Base 1
Pivot 1
Pivot 2

**team 3**
Base 1
Pivot 1
Pivot 2

After i generate teams i must be able to set status as "selected". If i need to create another team all users with status "selected" can't be use in another new team!

I currently use:

```
    $nteams=$_POST['teams']; 
    $nbase=$_POST['base'];
    $npivots=$_POST['pivots']; 
    $allplayers=$nteams*($nbase+$npivots);
    require_once "connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id FROM players ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $allplayers";
    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error()); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)<$allplayers) // sanity
      die('Not enough players!');
    else
      for($team=1;$team<=$nteams;$team++)
        {
        for($base=1;$base<=$nbase;$base++)
          {
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
          echo "Team $team Base $base = {$row['id']}<br />";
          }
        for($pivot=1;$pivot<=$npivots;$pivot++)
          {
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
          echo "Team $team Pivot $pivot  = {$row['id']}<br />";
          }
        }
    mysql_close();
```

Comment: You should totally use **"prepared statements"** for your `$sqlCommand`. It makes your script much more secure. check google for this

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `WHERE status<>'selected'` to your `$sqlCommand` statement
2. Store all read IDs from the database in an array, e.g. `$selectedIds`
3. Run update script `UPDATE players SET status='selected' WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', $selectedIds).')`

Side notes:

1. Consider rewriting the whole loop. It can be done in one `while` loop and one cursor/flag - let this be a homework :)
2. Beware of SQL Injection
3. You can wrap `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in a transaction to avoid inconsistency and conflicts

Comment: Best regards for trying helping me!